# Github Pages Background Image Not Showing Up

Tags: github-pages

I am new to website building and recently found out how to use Github Pages to build my own website on a domain I bought from Google Domains.

I have the photo I want to display in the hero section in the photos folder, titled `hero.jpg`. However, once I commit to GitHub, the photo doesn't show up.

I noticed that I cannot access `hero.jpg` at my-site.com/photos/hero.jpg so maybe this is the problem.

Could someone please advise me on the proper way to specify the path to images in HTML using the `url` function? Right now, I'm trying `background: url("assets/photos/hero.jpg")`

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Though i cannot find the said repository as the link is broken, i got similar issue of displaying background image.

This is my project tree structure

```
-- assets

   -- images

      -- image.jpg

   -- js

   -- css

      -- styles.css

index.html
```

**My background image didn't display when i did this**

`background: url("assets/images/image.jpg")`

**My background image displayed when i did this instead**

`background: url("../images/image.jpg")`

This has worked for me, i hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

On everything except OSX and Windows paths are case sensitive. Change the .jpg in your CSS to .JPG or rename the file in your git repo.